# Take out values from hash and insert in an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having

```
students = {1=>"alexandar", 2=>"mona", 3=>"gaga", 4=>"", 5=>"tom", 35=>"abcd", 44=>"hin"}
array = []
```

I had given this

```
array = students.values
```

and when I write in my test.js.erb

```
$('.show-test').text('<%= array%>')
```

it gives o/p

```
[&quot;alexandar&quot;, &quot;mona&quot;, &quot;gaga&quot;,
&quot;tom&quot;, &quot;abcd&quot;, &quot;hin&quot;]
```

Now I need to show text like this

```
 [alexander, mona, gaga, tom, abcd, hin]
```

Please guide me how to solve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Super simple, use [`Hash#values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values):

```
$> students = {1=>"alexandar", 2=>"mona", 3=>"gaga", 4=>"", 5=>..............}
$> students.values # <- Array with values
=> ["alexandar", "mona", "gaga", "", "tom", "abcd", "hin"]
```

### Update:

Use [`html_safe`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) if you trying to render json from controller.

```
$('.show-test').text('<%= array.html_safe %>')
```

or:

```
$('.show-test').text('<%= array.to_json.html_safe %>')
```

or (the same thing as `html_safe`):

```
$('.show-test').text('<%= raw(array.to_json) %>')
```

Comment: its giving me like this [&quot;alexandar&quot;, &quot;mona&quot;, &quot;gaga&quot;, &quot;tom&quot;, &quot;abcd&quot;, &quot;hin&quot;]

Comment: So, can you tell me, where is come from your hash? Looks like some `json` or something.

Comment: Ya exactly in js.erb I am doing this $('.show-test').text('<%= array%>')

Comment: @user123 you should clarify this case in a question )). Use one  of  `$('.show-test').text('<%= array.html_safe %>')` or `$('.show-test').text('<%= array.to_json.html_safe %>')`